# MS Graph API's subscription create to OnlineMessages fails

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, multi-tenant, subscription

I am attempting to create a subscription to the resource `/communications/onlineMeetings/?$filter=JoinWebUrl eq '{JoinWebUrl}'` with the node ms graph client.

To do this, I have:

- Two tenants, one with an active MS Teams license (Office 365 developer), whereas the other tenant houses my client app, which is a multi-tenant app.
- Added the required scope to the client app (App level scope: `OnlineMeetings.Read.All`)
- Given admin consent to the client app from the MS Teams tenant. The screenshot below shows the client app scope details in the MS Teams tenant.

[image: Client app scopes]

- Initialized the MSAL auth library as follows in the client app:

```
const authApp = new ConfidentialClientApplication({
  auth: {
    clientId: 'app-client-id',
    clientSecret: 'app-client-secret',
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}`,
  },
});
```

- Gotten an accessToken via the call:

```
const authContext = await authApp.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
  authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}`,
  scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'],
  skipCache: true,
});

const accessToken = authContext.accessToken;
```

- Initialized the MS Graph client as follows:

```
const client = MSClient.init({
  debugLogging: true,
  authProvider: (done) => {
    done(null, accessToken);
  },
});
```

- Created a subscription successfully for the: `CallRecords.Read.All` scope (which correctly sends call record notifications to the defined webhook) with the following call:

```
const subscription = await client
  .api('/subscriptions')
  .version('beta')
  .create({
    changeType: 'created,updated',
    notificationUrl: `https://my-ngrok-url`,
    resource: '/communications/callrecords',
    clientState: 'some-state',
    expirationDateTime: 'date-time',
});
```

- Attempted to create a subscription for the `OnlineMeetings.Read.All` scope with the following call:

```
const subscription = await client
  .api('/subscriptions')
  .version('beta')
  .create({
    resource: `/communications/onlineMeetings/?$filter=JoinWebUrl eq '{JoinWebUrl}'`,
    changeType: 'created,updated',
    notificationUrl: `https://my-ngrok-url`,
    clientState: 'some-state',
    expirationDateTime: 'date-time',
    includeResourceData: true,
    encryptionCertificate: 'serialized-cert',
    encryptionCertificateId: 'cert-id',
});
```

This results in the error message:

```
GraphError: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; 
Reason: The meeting tenant does not match the token tenant.]
```

I am unsure what is causing this and and how to debug it further. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @SrideviM clearly that cannot be the issue given the other subscription works correctly, no?

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/multi-tenant.md for msal initialization given multiple tenants and consented scopes for a client app. I believe the code is correct (at least per the docs). I do use `/common` endpoint for personal accounts when creating subscriptions against `me/events`, which also works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of the `joinWebUrl` in the resource definition was incorrect -- the joinWebUrl is a placeholder for an actual online-meeting's URL (rather than a catch-all for all created meetings).

What I was hoping to achieve however is (currently) not possible, which is creating a subscription on a particular user's join/leave events to any online-meeting.